# How to destroy Processing PApplet without calling exit()?

Tags: java, destructor, processing, finalizer

I working on a Processing program that runs in to different windows. On holds the controllers, thats the main *PApplet*, the other one is running some OpenGL and is a subclass of *PApplet* as well.

Creating an instance of the OpenGL window isn't too difficult but how do I `destroy()` it without calling `exit()` and killing the entire process. I just want to close the second window and free all it's resources.

I couldn't find any proper solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `PApplet.destroy()` does not cause a `System.exit()` call on its own.  Closing the `Frame` in which your PApplet runs, however, will.  You should be able to call `PApplet.destroy()` to terminate the main `PApplet` animation thread, and then call `frame.setVisible(false)` to close the window without triggering a `System.exit()` call.

In other words, try:

```
destroy();
frame.setVisible(false);
```

Comment: Thanks, I initialized the frame in the *PApplet* constructor. When I disposed the *PApplet* the frame got finalized and called `System.exit()`